# Using the jump if greater command in Assembly x86

Tags: arrays, loops, if-statement, assembly, x86

The following is my code:

```
.data

RUNS DWORD 2,1,9,2,7,4,4,0,7,3,10,4,2,1,14,5,10,4,10,7,3,7,6,8,0,5,2,5,4,0,7,6,1,0,5,7,3,5,3        ; Array
    DWORD 2,4,3,5,9,1,1,8,8,3,1,5,2,4
Space Byte " "
dash BYTE "=",0

zeros BYTE "0s   ",0
ones BYTE "1s   ",0
twos BYTE "2s   ",0
threes BYTE "3s   ",0
fours BYTE "4s   ",0
fives BYTE "5s   ",0
sixs BYTE "6s   ",0
sevens BYTE "7s   ",0
eights BYTE "8s   ",0
nines BYTE "9s   ",0
tens BYTE "10s  ",0


zero BYTE 0
one BYTE 0
two BYTE 0
three BYTE 0
four BYTE 0
five BYTE 0
six BYTE 0
seven BYTE 0
eight BYTE 0
nine BYTE 0
ten BYTE 0

.code
main PROC

    mov esi, OFFSET RUNS
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF RUNS
    mov eax, 0

    L1:

        mov eax,[esi]
        CALL Counter

        add esi,4

    loop L1

    mov al, zero
    mov edx, OFFSET zeros
    CALL WriteString
    mov cl, al

    L3:
        mov edx, OFFSET dash
        CALL WriteString
        mov eax, 100
        call delay

    loop L3
    CALL CRLF

    mov al, one
    mov edx, OFFSET ones
    CALL WriteString
    mov cl, al

    L4:
        mov edx, OFFSET dash
        CALL WriteString
        mov eax, 100
        call delay
    loop L4
    CALL CRLF

    mov al, two
    mov edx, OFFSET twos
    CALL WriteString
    mov cl, al

    L5:
        mov edx, OFFSET dash
        CALL WriteString
        mov eax, 100
        call delay
    loop L5
    CALL CRLF

    mov al, three
    mov edx, OFFSET threes
    CALL WriteString
    mov cl, al

    L6:
        mov edx, OFFSET dash
        CALL WriteString
        mov eax, 100
        call delay 
    loop L6
    CALL CRLF

    mov al, four
    mov edx, OFFSET fours
    CALL WriteString
    mov cl, al

    L7:
        mov edx, OFFSET dash
        CALL WriteString
        mov eax, 100
        call delay 
    loop L7
    CALL CRLF

    mov al, five
    mov edx, OFFSET fives
    CALL WriteString
    mov cl, al

    L8:
        mov edx, OFFSET dash
        CALL WriteString
        mov eax, 100
        call delay
    loop L8
    CALL CRLF

    mov al, six
    mov edx, OFFSET sixs
    CALL WriteString
    mov cl, al

    L9:
        mov edx, OFFSET dash
        CALL WriteString
        mov eax, 100
        call delay 
    loop L9
    CALL CRLF

    mov al, seven
    mov edx, OFFSET sevens
    CALL WriteString
    mov cl, al

    L10:
        mov edx, OFFSET dash
        CALL WriteString
        mov eax, 100 
        call delay 
    loop L10
    CALL CRLF

    mov al, eight
    mov edx, OFFSET eights
    CALL WriteString
    mov cl, al

    L11:
        mov edx, OFFSET dash
        CALL WriteString
        mov eax, 100 
        call delay 
    loop L11
    CALL CRLF

    mov al, nine
    mov edx, OFFSET nines
    CALL WriteString
    mov cl, al

    L12:
        mov edx, OFFSET dash
        CALL WriteString
        mov eax, 100 
        call delay
    loop L12
    CALL CRLF

    mov al, ten
    mov edx, OFFSET tens
    CALL WriteString
    mov cl, al

    L13:
        mov edx, OFFSET dash
        CALL WriteString
        mov eax, 100 
        call delay 
    loop L13
    CALL CRLF

    CALL CRLF
    CALL CRLF

    exit    
main ENDP   

Counter PROC

    .IF(eax == 0)
        add zero,1

    .ELSEIF(eax == 1)
        add one,1

    .ELSEIF(eax == 2)
        add two,1

    .ELSEIF(eax == 3)
        add three,1

    .ELSEIF(eax == 4)
        add four,1

    .ELSEIF(eax == 5)
        add five,1

    .ELSEIF(eax == 6)
        add six,1

    .ELSEIF(eax == 7)
        add seven,1

    .ELSEIF(eax == 8)
        add eight,1

    .ELSEIF(eax == 9)
        add nine,1

    .ELSEIF(eax == 10)
        add ten,1

    .ENDIF

    ret

Counter ENDP
END main
```

When you run it, it should look like this:

```
0s ====
1s ===
2s ====
3s ====
4s =====
5s =====
6s == 
7s ======
8s =
9s =
10s===
```

When you run the program, it will delay by 100 milliseconds and as a result, the dash "=" will print out in a gradual process. However, it must print out the whole row before the program can run the next row. So for example, 0s row must run first. It will gradually print out the dash "=" with a delay of 100 milliseconds. Then when that row is completed, it will go to the next row, which is 1's and start printing out the dash "=" gradually with a delay of 100 microseconds each dash "=". However, I want all the rows to run simultaneously. I know I have to use the jg, which is the jump if greater than. So if the number of dashes is greater than the row that is after the current row, it should jump to that row. So if the number of dashes in row 0s is greater than the number of dashes in 1s row, it should jump to 1s row. If 1s row has dashes greater than 2s row, it should jump to that row and continue increment the dashes. However, I am having difficulty doing that. Can someone provide assistance please. Thank you.

Comment: Um, remove all the delays?

Comment: i purposely put the delays there because i want to look like a race. Do you see where I am getting at? so each row must increment simultanously

Comment: *However, I want all the rows to run simultaneously.*  You mean you want to move the cursor back up to a previous line so you can go back and make the first line longer after printing an `'='` on later lines?  You can't do that with WriteString and CRLF.  You need to use some kind of full-screen-text functions.  IDK what Irvine32 has, but you need a new way to interact with the OS.  You might or might not need to use `jg` to do conditional jumps within your own code, but your title question is very different from what you're actually asking, if I understand correctly.

Comment: If Irvine is DOS based, you can search for "b800:0000 text mode" to learn how to address video ram directly (or use BIOS `int 10h`, but that's slower and IMO even more cumbersome than direct writes). If the executable is for modern OS, then you have to find some API which will allow you to draw at different place of terminal emulation console (as "tty" output stream is not capable to return back IIRC, so you need whole console emulation API).

Comment: BTW, I was unable to find some reference documentation listing all functions (also your original post doesn't show it's using irvine32.inc, so Peter probably knows some of the functions names to guess that? you should have stated that in question, as your code is not [mcve]), but I have seen in some example `call Clrscr`, so it looks like there are some extended functions working with screen space. Check the documentation of library you use.